# Ionic: issue with prod building

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, environment-variables, production-environment

I have a VERY strange bug which I have absolutely no idea how to debug.

When building my ionic app and launching on my Android, it works just fine. But, when I add the `--prod` flag - which I do every time I want to show something to the customer - I have that angular error :

```
 main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at t.get (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1
    at t (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at t.get (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1
    at t (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at t.get (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at oi (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at t.get (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
    at Qi (main.5e301c2a6dc3a49ec613.js:1)
```

And the app doesn't load at all. Not very helpfull - which is expected since it's `--prod`. I could very well rollback every change I made since the last time it worked, and check line by line... But it would take an awful amount of time, and also I really think there is a more logical way to get to it.

[EDIT] Ooookay, it's an issue with the deeplink plugin. If I remove

```
import {Deeplinks} from '@ionic-native/deeplinks/ngx';
private deeplinks: Deeplinks
```

from `app.components.ts` the error is gone. If I set it back the error is back.

[EDIT 2] I tried another plugin, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/ - same problem ! When building with `--prod` there is the same error !

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1450#issuecomment-447023921

Comment: Found some more clues, added to the question