# Deeplinking in hybrid apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, deep-linking, ionic4

Deeplinking in an Ionic hybrid app feels like something that should be really straightforward - but I really struggle to find an ideal solution.

- Official plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks is said now to be "community maintained" - looking at the code and the issues tracker it seems really not maintained that well. I tried it and got a big bug ( [Ionic: issue with prod building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936778/ionic-issue-with-prod-building) )
- On the github page, Ionic recommends another great solution : https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking but this one is part of something much bigger which I don't need at all.
- Finally I found also https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme which seems to recommend https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin for deeplinking - that one being archived and not maintained anymore.

What solution would you recommend, and if it's one of these three, how to overcome their flaws ?